# Bash script loop to count file size of all files in current directory?

Tags: bash, loops, count, byte, wc

Im very new to bash, and I have been given the task to write a bash script incorporating a loop that counts the byte size of all files in the current directory.

I want to use du but Ive been told he wants to see wc as the main command used.

As to how to make a loop accomplish these things, I'm unsure.
Can anyone give me an example or point me in the right direction?

Comment: There's too many possibilities to settle on just one, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
for fname in *; do
    your-way-to-display-size-of-file "$fname"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to gather several bits of bash know-how

to loop over files

```
for filename in * .[^.]*
do
    ...
done
```

to use the output of one command in another

```
command $(other_command ...)
```

to sum numbers in bash

```
count=$(($count + 1))
```

to count the number of bytes in a file with wc

```
wc -c $filename
```

Comment: It is not the first time I see the `* .[^.]*` trick mentioned. Even if I understand it, I don't like it because who knows if there is or not any file starting with 2 (or more) dots ? The for-loop should be over `*`, `.[^.]*` and `..?*` ;-). (Also, be careful because any subdirectory would be listed.)